# Defragment by format--copy-back

Tags: hard-drive, defragment

I want to do a defragment operation on my drive but I want it to be outside windows. This way, there will be no conflicts between files in-use and other issues.

Is a defragment operation the same thing as copying files from a drive to another, formatting that drive and re-copy those files back?
What about overhead and stress? format--copy-back vs a regular defragmentation?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows can defragment files even while they're in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably run into problems doing that, since you might wipe out your bootloader - A better solution would be to find a third party defragmenter that does [boot time defrag like defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler)

Defragmentation is likely to happen at a lower level than standard file operations (windows uses a specific api for this), so a simple delete and copy is unlikely to have the same effect.

Comment: Correct but when moving files it will place them one after another, making them contiguous. Isn't that the purpose of defragmentation? Thinking the API was built to be able to shift files around without creating a lock-down of the OS. For instance, using the OS and its files while a defragmentation process is running.

Comment: Well, it *should* but there's no real guarantee it would be done in a optimal manner. And there's the whole 'little' problem of possibly wiping out your bootloader. Its just not an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Diskeeper (http://www.condusiv.com) features Boot-Time Defragmentation and also comes with technology called HyperBoot that will actually improve boot-times itself.

-Alex